# Want to add same products using different IP addresses at the same time into the shopping cart

Tags: php, mysql, function

I am creating the ecommerce website in PHP. I am stuck now in shopping cart. When users of different IP addresses are adding the products which is already added by another users then that products are not coming in cart table of my database. For. exp. if user1 added "Book 1" in database, so user2 is not able to add "Book1" in database because Book1 is already added by user1. So I had try to solve this error but it is not getting solved.

// cart function:

```
function cart()
{
 if(isset($_GET['add_cart']))
{
 global $con;
 $ip = getIp();
 $cb_id = $_GET['add_cart'];
 $cart_query = "select * from cart where ip_add='$ip' AND cb_id='$cb_id'";
 $run_query = mysqli_query($con, $cart_query) or die(mysqli_error($con));


 if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query)>0)
{
 echo "<script>alert('You had already added this book in cart')</script>";
 echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
}
 else
{
 $insert_cart="insert into cart (cb_id, ip_add) values ('$cb_id','$ip')";
 $run_insert= mysqli_query($con, $insert_cart) or die(mysql_error($con));
 echo "<script>alert('Your book is added in the cart')</script>";
 echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
}
}
}
```

// IP function:

```
function getIp() 
{
 $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) 
{
 $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} 
 elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
{
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}

return $ip;
}
```

// cart table
cb_id (int 100)
ip_add (varchar 255)
qty text

Comment: dont use IP for a start users should have their own ids

Comment: the users are logged in? they should have an id each ..

Comment: mean you are trying to say I have  to use customer_id instead of ip_add in cart table.

Comment: Okzz so what changes i have to do in cart function to replace ip_add to customer_id

Comment: change `$ip` to what ever stores the customer id (sessions?)

Comment: i assume this is not a real site?

Comment: Okzz thank you for the replay. I will use customer_id. So can u please tell me how i will get customer_id in cart table instead of ip_add.

Comment: i dont know how your passing the customer ID from page to page, at a guess in sessions?

Comment: what are u trying to say?

Comment: I assume your practicing\learning, and not selling books

Comment: No buddy i am starting to sell the books online. I am new to php & web site designing that is why i am getting this type of questions

Comment: this is the line from which is i am getting book_id into the cart table:

Comment: <a href='index1.php?add_cart=$b_id' style='text-decoration:none'><button style='float:right;'> Add to Cart</button></a>

Comment: please install something prebuilt, this is not the kind of site to learn on.

Comment: I am learning from this site

Comment: well expect to be hacked, done all i can.

Comment: Okzz thank you for your advice. I will perfect then i will launch the website.